# Проблемы с запуском Visual Studio Code

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

Запускаю свой Windows. Мне смутило, что ярлык VS Code на рабочем столе стал такой, как испорченный:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решил нажать про ярлыку, а мне выдаёт такую ошибку....

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я ничего не делал, просто загрузил Windows. 2 года VS Code работал стабильно. Я понимаю, что можно перекачать заново, но у меня много чего там установленного, например, плагины. Кто сталкивался с такой же проблемой, и как вы решили её без потерь данных?

Самое интересное, что если залезть в фолдер VS Code и запустить какой-то Code.exe в глубине фолдера, то открывается нормально.

Comment: см. свойства ярлыка, пути

Comment: Путь верный....

Comment: Какие свойства на ярлыке. Если уж о проблеме заявляете, то деталей не помешало бы.

Comment: Прикрепил выше свойства

Comment: Ну удалите этот битый ярлык, делов-то. *"Code.exe в глубине фолдера, то открывается нормально"* - coбственно проблем запуском у вас нет.

Comment: Да, но когда я открываю в глубине фолдера Code.exe, то у меня отображается какой-то другой значок, будто не VS Code. Не очень приятно, хотя это мелочи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Советую переустановить приложение заново. А на будущее, если боитесь потерять свой настройки и плагины, залогиньтесь в Visual Studio Code через ваш аккаунт на GitHub и включите синхронизацию. Тогда ваши настройки и расширения будут сохранены на удалённом сервере, и вы сможете легко их восстановить на любой другой машине после входа в свой аккаунт.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хороший способ, но бэкапить настройки с расширениями все же не помешало отдельно. Особенно если вы что-то изменяли в коде расширения.